# Как в Visual Studio отредактировать текст, который появляется сразу после загрузки проекта?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как в Visual Studio отредактировать текст, который появляется сразу после загрузки проекта? Имеется в виду тот текст, который изображён на скриншоте.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как понять отредактировать? если вас такой ответ устроить, то ctrl+a и далее нажимаете delete

Comment: Я имел в виду то, чтобы при создании нового проекта сразу были бы написаны все команды препроцессора, которые я всегда использую, чтобы постоянно их не вводить.

Comment: Судя по вопросу вы хотите создать собственный шаблон проекта? Если так - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx в помощь

Comment: Спасибо большое